# extract from excel table based on another cells value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table, with a list of **temperatures on the left side** and a list of **pressures altitudes on the top**, then it has a value that is based on those two things in the table.

How do I make a formula that looks at another two cells that have the temperature and another that has the pressure altitudes, then looks at the table and finds where those two values meet on the table and gives me what is in the cell where those two meet?

For example,

I have two cells, one with temperature value 10 and another cell with pressure altitude value 1000, then looks on the table to find the cell where temp 10 and press alt 1000 meet and gives me the value in a different cell.

Comment: what are the format of your table (column rows)? An index / match will do it.

Comment: the column on the left has a list of tempratures and the row on the top has the Pressure altitude. then each cell has a value that corrosponds to each of those. so the top row is -2000, -1000, 0, 1000, 2000. and the left column is -50, -20, 0, 20, 50. and each cell on the actual table is the number that corrosponds to each of those.

Comment: This is covered well by [Pearson here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/lookups.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX` in its `Array` mode, like this

```
=INDEX(DataRange,MATCH(Temperature,TemperatureRange,0),MATCH(Pressure,PressureRange,0))
```

Note: this will only work if the Temperature and Pressure values explicitly exist in to table.  If you want to interpolate between tabulated values, it get quite a bit more complex.